# Get specific content from a string

Tags: php, string-matching

I need to get numbers as an array from a given string.

Example string:

```
$t = '1-P,2-T,3-P,4-R,5-C,6-T,';
```

Expected output:

- if I search `-T` the output needs to be like this:

```
array(
    [0] => 2,
    [1] => 6
)
```

- if it's `-P`:

```
array(
    [0] => 1,
    [1] => 3
)
```

---

I tried `var_export(explode("-T,",$t));` but it didn't work as expected.
Can any one give me a suggestion to get this?

Comment: Why would it return `3` only for `P` and not `1` too? After all, you have both `3-P` and `1-P`

Comment: I'm just waiting for the preg maniacs xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below matches the full integer number which preceeds the search term `-P`.
Let's keep it concise:

```
$matches = array();
if (preg_match_all('/([0-9]+)\-P/', $t, $matches) >= 1) {
    var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

Search for `'/([0-9]+)\-P/`, `'/([0-9]+)\-C/`, `'/([0-9]+)\-T/` an so on.

---

A more dynamic way to look for different search terms/filters:

```
$filter = '-T';
$pattern = sprintf('/([0-9]+)%s/', preg_quote($filter));
```

---

See [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) functions.

Comment: This solution is good because it finds the numbers that have length > 1 too. You could make it work with a variable, where the op can define what to search dinamically (`-P` / `-T` etc)

Comment: You are. I don't know preg / preg_functions. But the idea is there ;)

Comment: This is the best solution

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$t = '211111111131-P,2-T,3654554-P,4-R,5-C,6-T,';
$find = "-P";         // Search element
$found = [];          // Result array
$array = explode(",", $t);  // Breaking up into array 
foreach($array as $arr) {
    if (strpos($arr, $find)) {    // Checking if search element is found in $arr
       $found[] = explode('-',$arr)[0];  // Extracting the number prefix e.g 1 for 1-P
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 3
)
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but if it is like this $t = '211111111131-P,2-T,3654554-P,4-R,5-C,6-T,';  not working it returns only fist element.

Answer (score 1):

Use it as

```
$t = '1-P,2-T,3-P,4-R,5-C,6-T,';
$data = explode(",", $t);
print_r($data);
$row=array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($data); $i++) {
    if (!empty($data[$i])) {
        if (strpos($data[$i], '-T') !== false) {// pass find value here
            $final = explode("-", $data[$i]);
            $row[]=$final[0];
        }
    }
}
print_r($row);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 6
)
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/IhVkR)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$t = '1-P,2-T,3-P,4-R,5-C,6-T,';
$temp = [];
// if the last comma is not typo the 3rd argument `-1` omit empty item
$array = explode(",", $t, -1);
foreach($array as $arr) {
   list($v, $k) = explode('-', $arr);
   $temp[$k][] = $v;  
}

print_r($temp['T']);
```

**[demo](https://eval.in/606974)**

Comment: @KuppurajShanmugam what does mean "not working" - https://eval.in/607021

Answer (score 1):

Lots of good answers here already, but none take the approach of first putting the data into a better structure.

The code below converts the data to an associative array mapping letters to arrays of numbers, so that you can then do repeated lookups by whichever letter you want:

```
$t = '1-P,2-T,3-P,4-R,5-C,6-T,';

$a = array_filter(explode(',', $t));

$map = [];

foreach($a as $item) {
    $exploded = explode('-', $item);
    $number = $exploded[0];
    $letter = $exploded[1];
    if (!array_key_exists($letter, $map)) {
        $map[$letter] = [];
    }
    $map[$letter][] = $number;
}

print_r($map);
// Array
// (
//     [P] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => 1
//             [1] => 3
//         )
//
//     [T] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => 2
//             [1] => 6
//         )
//
//     [R] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => 4
//         )
//
//     [C] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => 5
//         )
//
// )

print_r($map['T']);
// Array
// (
//     [0] => 2
//     [1] => 6
// )
print_r($map['P']);
// Array
// (
//     [0] => 1
//     [1] => 3
// )
```